# Updating HelpNDoc script to locate library items in help topics

Tags: pascalscript, helpndoc

I am trying to write a script to use with HelpNDoc.

I am part way there:

```pascal
var
  aList: THndLibraryItemsInfoArray;
  nCnt: Integer;
begin
  // Get all items in the library
  aList := HndLibraryItems.GetItemList([]);
  
  // Go through each of them
  for nCnt := 0 to Length(aList) - 1 do
  begin
    // Is this a image (1)?
    // Is this a image map (9) ?
    if(HndLibraryItems.GetItemKind(aList[nCnt].id) = 1 or HndLibraryItems.GetItemKind(aList[nCnt].id) = 9) then
        // What is the default alternate text?
        var aDefaultAltText := HndLibraryItemsMeta.GetItemMetaStringValue(aList[nCnt].id, 'defaultalttext', '');

        // Update the alternate text if required
        if(aDefaultAltText = '') then
            // Now what do we do? We need to find all instances of where this library item has been used.
            // When we encounter one that has an alternate text description we update the meta.
            // How?
        end;

        // What is the default padding?
        var aDefaultPadding := HndLibraryItemsMeta.GetItemMetaIntValue(aList[nCnt].id, 'defaultpadding', 0);

        // Update padding if required
        if(aDefaultPadding = 0) then
            HndLibraryItemsMeta.SetItemMetaIntValue(aList[nCnt].id, 'defaultpadding', 5);
        end;
    end;
end.
```

I can:

- Iterate all library items
- Isolate all image / image map items
- Extract the default padding / alternate text values.
- Update the default padding value to 5 if it is 0.

The issue is with the alternate text. If it does not have a default value then I want to do this:

- Iterate all help topics
- Iterate all library items used in each help topic
- Find if the library item was used in that topic
- If it was, it gets alternate text value.
- If that value is not empty, apply it to the meta default value. Otherwise find the next instance.

If, by the end of iteration it did not find a alternate text value that was not empty it prints the library item name on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do what I wanted via the API.

Response from HelpNDoc:

> HelpNDoc's API doesn't include ways to *iterate over topic content*.